# Changing image with selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this fiddle earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/VmWD9/123/ which allows you to change an image within a page using a selection box, but I can't seem to get it to work with mine at all. Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
    <div class="orbit clean-hero-slider" role="region" data-orbit>
      <ul class="orbit-container">
        <li class="orbit-slide">
          <figure class="orbit-figure">
            <img class="orbit-image" src="img/products/product-01.jpg" alt="image alt text" name="myImage">
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li class="orbit-slide">
          <figure class="orbit-figure">
            <img class="orbit-image" src="img/products/product-01-2.jpg" alt="image alt text">
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li class="orbit-slide">
          <figure class="orbit-figure">
            <img class="orbit-image" src="img/products/product-01-3.jpg" alt="image alt text">
          </figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <!--<nav class="orbit-bullets">
      <button class="is-active" data-slide="1"><span class="show-for-sr">Lorem Ipsum Etiam</span></button>
      <button data-slide="2"><span class="show-for-sr">Lorem Ipsum Etiam</span></button>
      <button data-slide="3"><span class="show-for-sr">Lorem Ipsum Etiam</span></button>
    </nav> -->
  </div>

    <div class="cell small-4" style="border-left: 1px solid #d8d8d8;">
      <form method="" action="" name="myForm" class="custom-select" style="width:100%;">
  <select name="switch" onchange="switchImage();">
    <option value="1">Navy</option>
    <option value="2">Navy</option>
    <option value="3">Red</option>
  </select>
</form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>

// This is the code to preload the images
var imageList = Array();
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    imageList[i] = new Image(70, 70);
    imageList[i].src = "../img/products/product-0" + i + ".jpg";
}

function switchImage() {
    var selectedImage = document.myForm.switch.options[document.myForm.switch.selectedIndex].value;
    document.myImage.src = imageList[selectedImage].src;
}

</script>
```

Also, is it possible to make one of the select options change 3 images to 3 different images?

Comment: do you have the images in the directory specified ??

Comment: Second part yes. Keep changing the src you will achieve your answer.

Comment: @PrajvalM Yeah, they're in that directory so I'm unsure why they're not changing

Comment: Can you see any error in your developer log. press f12 on the right side you get red error marks if any errors are there.

Comment: @PrajvalM No errors in the console at all

Comment: try putting select inside form

Comment: @PrajvalM What do you mean?

Comment: it's a good practice to use select in forms although not a rule. I really doubt if the path specified is correct

Comment: @PrajvalM https://i.gyazo.com/cc57ad5911f2843758eaad3b8a5cf2bc.png here are the images within the folder specified

Comment: is your html file in htdocs or htdocs/someDir

Comment: @PrajvalM just htdocs i've tried with img/ and ../img/

Comment: try /img/.. also try commenting everything and just load the image

Comment: @PrajvalM It works when it's just the image, however when the slider code is around it, it doesn't work at all

Comment: remove all the classes first and then debug after you keep adding your classes. After that if you still get an error i will be able to answer.

Comment: @PrajvalM It seems to be only on mobile viewing that it doesn't work

Comment: so in your class there must be @media attribute in css which is making display:none or similar. Remove it and you are done.

Comment: @PrajvalM I have no display:none; in my slider other than to hide the options at the bottom

`clean-hero-slider .orbit-slide {
  padding-bottom: 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;

}

@media print, screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .clean-hero-slider .orbit-slide {
    padding-bottom: 0;
      height:100px;
  }
}
.clean-hero-slider ul.orbit-container {
  max-height:500px;
  height:500px;
    display:block;
}
.clean-hero-slider ul.orbit-container img {
  width:auto;

}`

Comment: remove @media query as you need a min-width of 40em to display the image

Comment: @PrajvalM The images display within the slider, they just don't change to the second image when it's selected from the selection box

Comment: @PrajvalM It doesn't work on mobile at all, even outside of the slider

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have posted works completely fine for me. Can, I know your exact problem?

Comment: Although I know you mean well, please don't post comments as answers. ;)

Comment: It doesn't for me at all, could it perhaps be something to do with the fact the image is a part of a slider carousel?

Comment: @Vishesh i've added the entire slider code to the original post, could this be effecting it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your image naming convention is different to the one you are building in your code.

**Images on page:**

```
product-01.jpg
product-01-2.jpg
product-01-3.jpg
```

**Images in array:**

```
product-01.jpg
product-02.jpg
product-03.jpg
```

Have you got these correct for the images in your `img` folder?

Comment: At the moment, I'm only trying to change the first image in the slider, I just changed the others for the example 

`<ul class="orbit-container">
        <li class="orbit-slide">
          <figure class="orbit-figure">
            <img class="orbit-image" src="img/products/product-01.jpg" alt="image alt text" name="myImage">
          </figure>
        </li>`

This is the one i'm trying to change - in my images folder they're named product-01.jpg for navy and product-02.jpg for red

Answer (score 0):

You declared an empty array variable.

So in your for loop, when it sets imageList[i], there isn’t an item at position imageList[i]. you need to use the array.push method to add items to your array.

```
var imageList = Array();
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var img = new Image(70, 70);
    img.src = "../img/products/product-0" + i + ".jpg";
    imageList.push(img);
}
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way to get it to work on mobile?

Comment: What functionality do you require for ‘mobile’?

Comment: I just need the image to change with the selection box on mobile also, as it only works on desktop at the moment